# Fixed-sized array gets erased after passed as argument to a ByRef Variant parameter in procedure

Tags: vba, vb6

While testing a VBA procedure I've encountered a behaviour I can't explain.

```
Sub TestFixedSizeArrayAsByRefVariantArgument()
    Dim Arr(0) As Long
    Arr(0) = 99
    DoSomethingWithArray Arr
    Debug.Print Arr(0)
End Sub

Sub DoSomethingWithArray(ByRef ArrayArg As Variant)
    Dim localArr(0) As Long
    localArr(0) = -1
    If IsArray(ArrayArg) Then ArrayArg = localArr
End Sub
```

The output of Debug.Print Arr(0) is 0, although I would have expected it either to be -1 or at least 99. But it seems the elements in Arr are getting erased (set to 0) after the call to DoSomethingWithArray.
Can anybody explain this behaviour?

When I change the array declaration to

```
    Dim Arr As Variant
    ReDim Arr(0) As Long
```

I'm getting the expected result -1.
Same with just

```
    ReDim Arr(0) As Long
```

So it seems to work as expected with a dynamic-sized array. But what's the problem to call DoSomethingWithArray with a fixed-size array?

Comment: Is the question why doesn't the assignment work? Or why is the original array erased? Or both?

Comment: My question is: why is the original array erased? Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: Seems to be related to Static array (declared with bounds) vs Dynamic array (declared without bounds)

Comment: You can only copy a static array (arr & localarr) to a dynamic array (ArrayArg).  The assignment ArrayArg = localArr is a static being assigned to a dynamic array, but the dynamic array being referenced to a static array is what is causing this odd behavior.  You can however, assign a value like ArrayArg(0) = 50 within the function, it will assign and retain Arr(0) as 50. Inside and outside the function.

Comment: I've assigned ArrayArg(0) = 50 after the assignment ArrayArg = localArr in the function. It still shows Arr(0) = 0 after leaving the function.
But you're right, if I comment out the assignment ArrayArg = localArr it retains Arr(0) as 50 outside the function.